# How to make td tags move when clicked to available cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current table:

[image: Click here to view the table]

Each cell can only move if it has a white cell next to it, and proceed to switch positions with that white cell. (I'm trying to do the Parking Lot puzzle game).
I'm not sure if using a table is the right choice, is there an easier way to do this?
Here is what I have so far:

```html
<table style="width: 650px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid #000000">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 23px;">
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px; background-color: blue"  ></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: blue" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 23px;">
            <td style="width: 49px; height: 23px; background-color: green" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: red" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px; background-color: yellow"></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: yellow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 23px;">
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: yellow"></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: yellow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 23px;">
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px; background-color: blue"  ></td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 24px; height: 23px;background-color: blue" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a table. I would use canvas

Answer (score 1):

With using tables, this will get messy very fast. This is because, like you illustrated, will have to make use of the `colspan` and `rowspan` properties, and these properties will have to change for multiple cells at the same time with some complex logic. Also, possibly animations of the cells switching are a bit harder too. Therefore, this method of using tables is not recommended.

Possible other solutions would be the use of div's with absolute positioning, or even better the use of a canvas.